# How do I search through an XML file recursively?

Tags: c#, xml, recursion, search

I would like to search in a XML-File for Nodes, that have the name "Reference".
The inner Text of these nodes are other xml-Files. I also want to parse these xml-Files for the same nodes ("Reference").

I use some methods to set the name and Path of the references I found, but I don't know how to do it recursive.

The class, where I search and set the Name and Path of the reference I found in the XML

```
public class SetReferences
{
    public SetReferences(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(args[0]);
        XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        ns.AddNamespace("msbld", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");
        XmlNodeList nodelist = doc.SelectNodes("//msbld:Reference", ns);
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist)
        {

            var file = new FileInfo(node.InnerText);
            AnalyzedAssembly analyzedAssembly = new AnalyzedAssembly
                {
                    AssemblyName = file.Name,
                    AssemblyFile = file
                };


                Console.WriteLine(analyzedAssembly.AssemblyName);
                Console.WriteLine(analyzedAssembly.AssemblyFile);
        }
    }
}


public class AnalyzedAssembly
{
    public string AssemblyName { get; set; }
    public FileInfo AssemblyFile { get; set; }        
    public List<AnalyzedAssembly> ChildDepencies { get; } = new List<AnalyzedAssembly>();

}
```

That's my Main

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new SetReferences(args);

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

}

The XML files look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="DataMatrix.net, Version=1.0.0.0>
      <HintPath>..\packages\DataMatrix.net.0.4.2\lib\20\DataMatrix.net.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Devart.Data, Version=5.0.1289.0>
      <HintPath>..\..\lib\ExtLib\DevArt\Devart.Data.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

I want all References listed. There exists a xml-File for each Reference. I want to search in these for "References of the Reference".

Right now I get all References of this XML above, but the search is not resursive.

The backround is that I have to search in the source code of all references included in the project for SQL-Statements. For this I first need all references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

indeed I'm modifying my answer

To implement a recursive algorithm you need to establish the so called recursion pivot, which is to say that object that will contain instances of itself.
In this case for you is the XMLFile

So you will have:
1) The induction method that will accept for sure a string representing the file name
2) The body of the recursive method which will parse the file and will store result in a collection
3) The actual recursive call
4) Result printing

Something that would look like this

```
public SetReferences(String[] args)
{
    List<AnalyzedAssembly> analyzedAssembly;
    analyzedAssembly.add(buildAnalyzedAssembly(args[0]);
    analyzedAssembly.addAll(recursion(args[0])); // Root XML file

    // Print result by using analyzedAssembly
}

private List<AnalyzedAssembly> recursion(String xmlFileName) {
    List<AnalyzedAssembly> analyzedAssembly = new ArrayList<>();
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    ns.AddNamespace("msbld", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");
    XmlNodeList nodelist = doc.SelectNodes("//msbld:Reference", ns);
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist) {
        // Create an instance of AnalyzedAssembly and perform recursive call
        analyzedAssembly.add(node.InnerText); // Use XML file name in node
        analyzedAssembly.addAll(recursion(node.InnerText));

    }
    // Finally return list
    return analyzedAssembly;
}

private AnalyzedAssembly buildAnalyzedAssembly(String xmlFileName) {
    var file = new FileInfo(xmlFileName); // Build file with the name given in input
    AnalyzedAssembly analyzedAssembly = new AnalyzedAssembly
        {
            AssemblyName = file.Name,
            AssemblyFile = file
        };
    return analyzedAssembly;
}
```

Comment: How can I do this with a for loop?

Comment: Hey @idontcare I modified my response, I misread the first sentence in your question.

Comment: It worked with this solution, after a few customazions. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know the exact syntax of the methods, I can just provide some description...
So, try to separate the actual searching into a method, say *bar*, for itself, which takes a list of nodes as input, works with the found nodes, processes the inner text to nodes and call itself on all child nodes which meet the condition.
So, you do all your preparations first and call the separated method *bar* once.

EDIT:
I did not complie the code or anything, so there could be planty of errors. I think, this could help to go a step further.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new SetReferences(args);

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private SetReferences(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(args[0]);
        XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        ns.AddNamespace("msbld", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");
        XmlNodeList nodelist = doc.SelectNodes("//msbld:Reference", ns);
        HandleNodes(nodelist);
    }

    private HandleNodes(XmlNodeList[] nodes)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist)
        {

            var file = new FileInfo(node.InnerText);
            AnalyzedAssembly analyzedAssembly = new AnalyzedAssembly
            {
                AssemblyName = file.Name,
                AssemblyFile = file
            };


            Console.WriteLine(analyzedAssembly.AssemblyName);
            Console.WriteLine(analyzedAssembly.AssemblyFile);

            // Get a new nodelist from the inner XML
            // and call HandleNodes on this new nodelist here.
        }
    }
}

public class AnalyzedAssembly
{
    public string AssemblyName { get; set; }
    public FileInfo AssemblyFile { get; set; }        
    public List<AnalyzedAssembly> ChildDepencies { get; } = new List<AnalyzedAssembly>();

}
```

Comment: Thanks! But where do I get a new nodelist from? In my Reference of the first xml is the Path of the Reference xml. And this path is in the FileInfo format

Comment: Could you provide a small example for such an XML? I'm not sure if I understand it correctly...

Comment: Added it to the question

Comment: Ok, as @sergio-arrighi mentioned in an other answer, your structure is already flat. Have you looked at this site? [link](http://www.csharp-examples.net/xml-nodes-by-name/)

Comment: No sorry I did misread the first sentence of the question :'( I updated my answer too